# How do I change .css versioning?

Tags: customization

What I mean is - one of my .css files has an appended .css?v=1.1.2

How do I make it a 1.1.3? I thought that that would be automatic but after a forced flush of the cache, the same version is there.

I took a look at my `header.php` file and this is what I see:

```
<?php        
 if (is_page_template('page-cars.php')) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flag-icon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flag-icon.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'conferences', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/cars.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'conferences', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cars.js', array(), '1.0.1', true );
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In using the `wp_enqueue_style` you can set a version number similar to how you set the script.

### Codex Example:

```
wp_enqueue_style( string $handle, string $src = false, array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, string $media = 'all' )
```

### Your Code

Say you want to update the 'conferences' CSS from above.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'conferences', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/cars.css', array(), '1.3.1' );
```